# What is this type of graphic design called?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, style

Do you know what is this type of graphic design called? More precisely I mean characters with "shadows", any Youtube tutorials? I use Adobe Illustrator. Here are some examples:

- Starbucks Logo https://img.favpng.com/5/0/16/cafe-coffee-starbucks-logo-png-favpng-Yq3byjqEiPKtuhHNZFJUtX39v.jpg
- Dribble https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/31065/screenshots/5902626/srcc_crest_2x.jpg
- [image]

Comment: Based upon all 3 samples.... I'd merely say 1 color, high contract, character Illustration.

Comment: It's meant to simulate a woodcut or linocut print.

Answer (score 3):

That Poseidon emblem could be understood as a simple 1-color or 2-color linocut or woodcut style, mainly because of the sawtooth shading technique. The linked examples are less traditional and might simply be referred to as minimal flat 1-color or 2-color spot illustration. To locate some tutorials search the following phrase: ***"1 color linocut illustration vector tutorials"*** and view the resulting images. The results should be in the same visual neighborhood as your examples and hopefully some are associated with a useful tutorial. Swap out "woodcut" for "linocut" and search again. Also, searching for 'linocut' or 'woodcut' vector brushes may be beneficial. Good luck.

Pete